# Linux Subversion configuration file

Tags: svn, debian-squeeze, ssh-tunnel, rabbitvcs

I've moved my SVN repo from one host to another. The new host requires I commit by using svn+ssh:// instead of https:// like my previous host did.

One issue I can't escape is no matter what I do I get this error when I checkout or commit my changes:

```
To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

I've modified the config file located on my home drive and the root area, I still get that message.

Now oddly enough, I was able to get the repo by using the command line but if I use either GUI tool I have on my Linux box I get that message.

I'd highly prefer not to have to commit by command-line, so if anyone can tell me how I remove that -q flag it seems to keep saying exists, it will make my day.

Currently, both config files have the value setup like so, let me know if it's wrong:

```
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o ControlMaster=no
```

I did it with both the # sign is placed and removed.

I'm out of ideas and need some insight.

Comment: A very common reason for this error is that the svn URL is improperly formatted--like a missing username etc.   What URL are you using in the new configuration?

Comment: the instructions was written for cli usage, so i took out the cli stuff like svn checkout --username=xxx and just used the svn+ssh:// url for the url.

Comment: I tested the same url on my windows machine, it works just fine, so now I'm stumped. I do 99% of my work on linux so it'll help if it works there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the gui tool i'm using has a known problem with that sort of svn connection, but I've noticed netbeans svn tool works, so I'll just use that until RabbitVCS resolves that longstanding bug.